# Qt antialiasing sets different pen widths

Tags: c++, qt, antialiasing

I have a `qt` app which has a big `QGraphicsView` where I draw a grid.

This grid reacts on mouse clicks. Basically, if you click on some box -> the box is made red. And if you double click on it -> it goes back to its original state (its white).

This is the implementation of my `QGraphicsView`:

```
#include "mapview.h"

// Constructors

mapview::mapview()
{
    setUpGui();
}

mapview::mapview(QWidget *parent) : QGraphicsView(parent)
{
    setUpGui();
}

// GUI setup

void mapview::setUpGui()
{
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);

    this->setScene(scene);
    this->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
//    this->setRenderHint(QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing);
}

// Events

void mapview::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
        lastPoint = event->pos();
        scribbling = true;
    }
}

void mapview::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if ((event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) && scribbling)
    {
        drawWall(event->pos());
    }
}

void mapview::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton && scribbling)
    {
        drawWall(event->pos());
        scribbling = false;
    }
}

void mapview::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    removeWall(event->pos());
}

// Drawing methods

void mapview::drawGrid(const int box_count)
{
    scene->clear();

    auto x = 0.0;
    auto y = 0.0;

    this->margin = 20.0;

    _width = this->width() - 2 * margin;
    _height = this->height() - 2 * margin;

    if (fabs(_width - _height) >= std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon())
    {
//        qDebug() << "width (" << width <<  ") != height (" << height << ")";
        return;
    }

    this->box_count = box_count;
    this->box_size = _width / box_count;



    // Horizontal
    for (auto i = 0; i <= box_count; i++)
    {
        QGraphicsLineItem *line = new QGraphicsLineItem(x, y, x + _width, y);
        QPen pen;
        pen.setColor(Qt::black);
        line->setPen(pen);
//        scene->addLine(x, y, x + _width, y);
        scene->addItem(line);
        y += box_size;
    }

    y = 0.0;

    // Vertical
    for (auto i = 0; i <= box_count; i++)
    {
        scene->addLine(x, y, x, y + _height);
        x += box_size;
    }
}

void mapview::drawWall(const QPointF &endPoint)
{
    auto x = endPoint.x() - margin;
    auto y = endPoint.y() - margin;

    x = static_cast<int>(x / box_size) * box_size;
    y = static_cast<int>(y / box_size) * box_size;

    QGraphicsRectItem* rect = new QGraphicsRectItem(x, y, this->box_size, this->box_size);
    rect->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::red));
    rect->setPen(QPen());
    scene->addItem(rect);
}

void mapview::removeWall(const QPointF &point)
{
    auto x = point.x() - margin;
    auto y = point.y() - margin;

    x = static_cast<int>(x / box_size) * box_size;
    y = static_cast<int>(y / box_size) * box_size;

    QGraphicsRectItem* rect = new QGraphicsRectItem(x, y, this->box_size, this->box_size);
    rect->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::white));
    rect->setPen(QPen());
    scene->addItem(rect);
}
```

As you can see at the top, I set up antialiasing. The problem is, that when I set it up, it somehow changes the view of my drawing:

This is the view of an untouched grid:

[image]

Now for the box `1x1` (indexed from `0`) I've clicked it (made it red) and then I double clicked it (so it got back to its original state). The problem is, as you can see, the border of this box is kinda thicker:

[image]

Funny thing is, that it's only thicker on this view. If I zoom it in, there's no difference between its border and the borders of other boxes. The other thing is, if I set `Qt::HighQualityAntialiasing` -> the border is the same, but then the zooming gets laggy, I guess it has to do more heavy computations or something like this.

So my question here would be: Is there a way, to make the antialiasing not change the thickness of the border? (I mean, I know it doesn't really change it, but you can definitely see a difference here)

Comment: Definitely not. Even on my phone I see the bottom picture different. By saying `1x1` I mean from the top left corner

Comment: My fault, was looking at the wrong cell ;)

Comment: Try using sub-pixel coordinates instead, like <0.5, 0.5> instead of <0, 0>

Comment: Well, I actually fixed the problem by not redrawing the box in white but just removing the old one from the scene, but I didn't know if I should delete my question or not, as it may be helpful to other people having this issue.

Comment: If you solved your issue I'd recommend you to publish your solution as an answer and accept it (you'll have to wait 2 days to mark it as solved). In this way your contribution will be more useful. If possible, explain how did it affected you or why it solves the issue: other ones may have a _similar_ problem and your arguments may help them better than the solution itself.